# C# Regular expression hard drive issue

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to have a regular expression in a case of if the user chose a hard drive (e.g. "C:\" drive).
I've tried:

```
Match reg = Regex.Match(location, @"/[A-Z][:][\\]/");
```

And:

```
Match reg = Regex.Match(location, "/[A-Z][:][\\]/");
```

The 1st line doesn't detect, the 2nd line ends with an exception: [System.ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHArgument%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true)

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you, thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, you want to check that the string is exactly something like `C:\`, but not something like `ABC:\\ and my dog`. You need the anchors `^` and `$`:

```
^[A-Z]:\\$
```

In code:

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(yourstring, @"^[A-Z]:\\$");
```

Note that I have removed the brackets you had in `[:]` and `[\\]` (not necessary since in each of these cases we are matching a single literal character, not one character from a class of several possible characters).

Answer (score 4):

Remove the leading and trailing `/` characters from the pattern; they're not part of the .NET regex syntax.

Comment: As seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43122zyz.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler than you've got. All you need is this:

```
Match reg = Regex.Match(location, @"^[A-Z]:\\$");
```

- The `@"..."` syntax is a verbatim string, which simplifies regexes (and paths).
- `^` will force the match to succeed only if it's at the start of the string
- `[A-Z]` is as you had, matching the drive letter.
- `:\\` are the literal characters `:` and `\`, with the backslash doubled up so the regex doesn't try to treat it specially.
- `$` will force the match to succeed only if it's at the end of the string

The ^ and $ thus force it to match the whole input string, rather than potentially matching a string in the middle.